Manipulate rotation of image using im2pdf. Parameter doesn't work as expected?
I am trying to take images and convert them to PDFs, however, when an image has a rotation value in its exif data, then my pdf also has a rotation value on the converted pdf.
Instead of having the rotation value on the pdf page, i want the image to be rotated as it is meant to be viewed based on the image's exif, and not have any rotation value on the pdf page.
How do i accomplish this ?
I'm hoping to be able to do this only using img2pdf.
I am using this command:
pdf_bytes = img2pdf.convert(io.BytesIO(response.content), rotation=img2pdf.Rotation.ifvalid, first_frame_only=True)

And the input file is :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JyCBl5ulQmKIdQnVsvbNo7oNHX7oGIda/view?usp=sharing
The input file has a 90CW rotation as per exif data.
However, whether i generate the pdf using rotation=img2pdf.Rotation.ifvalid or not, the generated pdf is the same. Why does it not make any difference ?
My goal is for the image to be rotated as per exif and the pdf to not have any rotation value on the pdf page.
I am checking the page rotation of the output using this code:
from pypdf import PdfReader

with open('abc.pdf', 'rb') as input_pdf:
    reader = PdfReader(input_pdf)
    
    # Iterate through each page and get the rotation value
    for page_num, page in enumerate(reader.pages):
        # Get the rotation value of the page
        rotation_value = page.get('/Rotate') or 0  # Default to 0 if not rotated
        
        print(f"Page {page_num + 1} is rotated by {rotation_value} degrees.")

Output:
Page 1 is rotated by 90 degrees.


Img2PDF is lossless thus it has no ability to alter the image to match the page dimensions.
This is explained in part by how it works :-

img2pdf directly embeds the image data into the PDF without re-encoding it. It thus treats the PDF format merely as a container format for the image data. In these cases, img2pdf only increases the filesize by the size of the PDF container (typically around 500 to 700 bytes). Since data is only copied and not re-encoded, img2pdf is also typically faster than other solutions for these input formats.

Also in part by the software author:-

You are correct in concluding that img2pdf currently is unable to apply rotation on a per-image basis.


But I'm also very hesitant about adding such a feature. The same argument that you made could not only be made for the image rotation but also for all the other settings which currently affect all the images at once. So should img2pdf add a way to also specify the following on a per-image basis?

The author is willing to accept any sensible patch, just not adding complexity for specific usages. Simply consider other means of specify command line rotation.
https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf/issues/190

Have a look at imagemagick. They do support a syntax like -r -90< , telling it to apply this only on images which are wider than high, thus effektively rotating selectively.

Personally I would either use any image rotate (without magick) then lossless insert OR better, accept the image is rotated, and then use PDF page rotation.

Hi,
Thanks for explaining that.
Can you also please explain what this parameter is expected to do then ? I thought this was meant to handle rotation use cases similar to mine: "rotation=img2pdf.Rotation.ifvalid"
